# Starling lacks MovieClip usage, what graphic do I use?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I've just recently added the Starling Framework to my new project.  However, I've noticed that I can't use MovieClips with it.

There is no Starling equivalent to the Flash `import flash.display.MovieClip;`

So what graphic type does Starling expect users to use?

Comment: Instead of normal Flash objects, Starling works with textures and texture atlases. You should start with reading Starling Manual carefully, it briefly explains all of it: http://manual.starling-framework.org/en/

Answer (score 0):

flash.display.MovieClip is not a graphics-type, it's a container. 
In Starling, a MovieClip is a way to display animations, a timeline of images/textures.